# How to filter records from an api server according to some specific properties in redux using axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios

I am working on a Blog project in redux where I am calling data from an api server and trying to display the default data(for now I am trying to retrieve the default data,I haven't implemented posting to the api server as of now) from the server.The data contains posts that are posted by users on the blog.The default data for the api server looks like this:

```
const defaultData = {
  "8xf0y6ziyjabvozdd253nd": {
    id: '8xf0y6ziyjabvozdd253nd',
    timestamp: 1467166872634,
    title: 'Udacity is the best place to learn React',
    body: 'Everyone says so after all.',
    author: 'thingtwo',
    category: 'react',
    voteScore: 6,
    deleted: false,
    commentCount: 2
  },
  "6ni6ok3ym7mf1p33lnez": {
    id: '6ni6ok3ym7mf1p33lnez',
    timestamp: 1468479767190,
    title: 'Learn Redux in 10 minutes!',
    body: 'Just kidding. It takes more than 10 minutes to learn technology.',
    author: 'thingone',
    category: 'redux',
    voteScore: -5,
    deleted: false,
    commentCount: 0
  }
}
```

So,what I am trying to do is, I want to filter out the posts based on a category.So,I have the homepage which lists all the categories available.So,when the user clicks on a category,he/she will be taken to a page where the posts for that category are shown.

The redux's **"Action"** file for filtering out the posts according to a particular category is given below:

```
import axios from 'axios';
export const FETCH_CATEGORIES = 'fetch_categories';
export const FETCH_PARTICULAR_CATEGORY_POSTS = 'fetch_particular_category';


let token;
if (!token)
  token = localStorage.token = Math.random().toString(32).substr(-8);
const API = 'http://localhost:3001';
const headers = {
                  'Accept' : 'application/json',
                  'Authorization' : 'token'
}

//Action creaor for fetching all the categories available
export function fetchCategories() {
  const URL = `${API}/categories`;
  const request = axios.get(URL,{headers});

  return dispatch => {
        return request.then((data) => {
          dispatch({
            type : FETCH_CATEGORIES,
            payload : data
          })
        })
  }
}

//Action creator to fetch all the available posts for a particular category
export function fetchPostWithCateogry(category) {
  const URL = `${API}/${category}/posts`;
  const request = axios.get(URL,{headers});

  return dispatch => {
      return request.then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
          dispatch({
            type: FETCH_PARTICULAR_CATEGORY_POSTS,
            payload: data
          })
      })
  }
}
```

The component file for displaying the posts of a particular category is:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { fetchPostWithCateogry } from '../actions/categories_action';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class CategoryView extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { category } = this.props.match.params;
    this.props.fetchPostWithCateogry(category);
    console.log(category);
  }

    render() {
      const { category } = this.props;
      console.log(category);

      if (!category) {
        return <div>Loading...</div>
      }

      return(
          <div>
            <h3>category.title</h3>
            <h5>category.category</h5>
            <h6>category.body</h6>
          </div>
      );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps({ categories },ownProps) {
    return { category: categories[ownProps.match.params.category]}
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchPostWithCateogry})(CategoryView);
```

The **reducer** file for the same is:

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import { FETCH_CATEGORIES, FETCH_PARTICULAR_CATEGORY_POSTS } from '../actions/categories_action';

export default function(state={}, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
      case FETCH_CATEGORIES:
        return {categories: {...state.categories, ...action.payload.data.categories}};
        //return {categories: [...state.categories]};

        case FETCH_PARTICULAR_CATEGORY_POSTS:
        console.log(action.payload);
        return  {...state, [action.payload]: action.payload};

        default:
          return state;
    }
}
```

I am using **Route** to navigate to the component depending on the endpoint the user entered.The index file for the same is given below:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reducers from './reducers/index.js'
import Posts from './components/posts_index';
import CreatePost from './components/new_post';
import PostDetail from './components/post_detail';
import CategoryView from './components/category';

const createStoreWithMiddleware = createStore(reducers,applyMiddleware(thunk));

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <Route  path="/new" component={CreatePost} />
          <Route path="/posts/:id" component={PostDetail} />
          <Route exact  path="/" component={Posts} />
          <Route path="/:category/posts" component={CategoryView} />   
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>  , document.getElementById('root'));
```

So,I am talking about the last route above.Now,the problem is, I do not get any errors,but the posts  for a category are not being displayed.But if I try to console.log the request response returned from axios,I can see the required result,i.e.,I see the post with the category which is enter in my route url.A screenshot of the output of console.log that I get is attached below:

[image: output]

Can anyone please suggest where am I going wrong? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT 1:**
After trying to use redux devtools,I get the below error as shown in the screenshot:

[image: actions_error]

**EDIT 2**
the output of promise:

[image: promise_output]

**NOTE** I get the error only when I try to use redux devtools.Am I doing something wrong while using it.Below is my index file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reducers from './reducers/index.js'
import Posts from './components/posts_index';
import CreatePost from './components/new_post';
import PostDetail from './components/post_detail';
import CategoryView from './components/category';

const createStoreWithMiddleware = createStore(reducers,applyMiddleware(thunk),window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ &&
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__());

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <Route  path="/new" component={CreatePost} />
          <Route path="/posts/:id" component={PostDetail} />
          <Route exact  path="/" component={Posts} />
          <Route path="/:category/posts" component={CategoryView} />
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>  , document.getElementById('root'));
```

**Edit 3:**

Actions in redux devtools:
[image: payload]

**Edit 4**
redux devtools State screenshot

[image: State]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit : I edited all my post to make it clear.

Your reducer :

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import { FETCH_CATEGORIES, FETCH_PARTICULAR_CATEGORY_POSTS } from '../actions/categories_action';

export default function(state={}, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
      case FETCH_CATEGORIES:
        return {categories: {...state.categories, ...action.payload.data.categories}};
      case FETCH_PARTICULAR_CATEGORY_POSTS:
          return  {...state, [action.category]: action.payload.data};
        default:
          return state;
    }
}
```

Your action :

```
export function fetchPostWithCateogry(category) {
  const URL = `${API}/${category}/posts`;
  const request = axios.get(URL,{headers});

  return dispatch => {
      return request.then((data) => {
          dispatch({
            type: FETCH_PARTICULAR_CATEGORY_POSTS,
            payload: data,
            category
          })
      })
  }
}
```

Now we pass the `category` property to the action to name the index in which we'll store our array of posts.

You'll access this array of posts in your component but you need to iterate in this array to display his content :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { fetchPostWithCateogry } from '../actions/categories_action';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class CategoryView extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { category } = this.props.match.params;
    this.props.fetchPostWithCateogry(category);
    console.log(category);
  }

    render() {
      const { category } = this.props;
      console.log(category);

      if (!category) {
        return <div>Loading...</div>
      }

      return(
          <div> {category.map(post => (<h3>{post.title}</h3>))}
          </div>
      );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps({ categories },ownProps) {
    return { category: categories[ownProps.match.params.category]}
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchPostWithCateogry})(CategoryView);
```

Comment: I tried it the way you mentioned.But it isn't working.

Comment: I get the same output in my console.log as shown in the screenshot above

Comment: Can you give a try to [Redux-devtools for chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd) to see what's in your store and if your actions are correctly dispatched.

Comment: okay,just let me try it out.give me few mins.I will let you know the result

Comment: I tried using redux devtools and it gives the error which  I have mentioned in a screenshot above in an edit.Can you please have a look?I am not able to figure how to proceed.

Comment: This is weird because you are using thunk to handle async actions, you can try what i added in my post to see if it comes from the way you use `mapDispatchToProps`

Comment: I tried it the exact way you mentioned.But still it gives the same error.I removed the 2nd parameter from connect() and added dispatch to componentDidMount()

Comment: I edited again, i think this is because your `request.then()` returns nothing.

Comment: I get the output in my console.log with the data.I have mentioned above with a screenshot.Also,the error appears only when I use redux devtools. I have also pasted my index file with how I am using redux devtools. Am I doing something wrong in that?

Comment: Your store declaration should be like this : `const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;`

`const createStoreWithMiddleware = createStore(reducers, composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk)));`

You'll also need to import `compose` from redux

Comment: Great,now the error is gone.Thanks.But still I don't see the data in my component but I can see the filtered data in my console when I try to console.log the promise response

Comment: So,in redux devtools in my action I can see the payload returning the data.

Comment: I have posted the screenshot of the actions in devtools. Can you please have a look.Is it how it should be?

Comment: Your action `type` should be `FETCH_PARTICULAR_CATEGORY_POSTS`, have you changed that in your request promise ?

Comment: yes,I have the same as my type.This is how my promise looks: return dispatch => {
      return request.then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
          dispatch({
            type: FETCH_PARTICULAR_CATEGORY_POSTS,
            payload: data
          })
      })
  }
}

Comment: I got it, you have to change this : `export const FETCH_PARTICULAR_CATEGORY_POSTS = 'fetch_particular_category';`
use `'FETCH_PARTICULAR_CATEGORY_POSTS'` instead

Comment: You mean instead of       export const FETCH_PARTICULAR_CATEGORY_POSTS = 'fetch_particular_category'; I need to just write  export 'FETCH_PARTICULAR_CATEGORY_POSTS'..Sorry I didn't get exactly what you said

Comment: Your action type needs to be the string `'FETCH_PARTICULAR_CATEGORY_POSTS'` but you're calling the const `FETCH_PARTICULAR_CATEGORY_POSTS` which you declared as equal to `'fetch_particular_category'`, you can remove this declaration and call directly the string `'FETCH_PARTICULAR_CATEGORY_POSTS'` when you dispatch your action or keep your const and change his value : `export const FETCH_PARTICULAR_CATEGORY_POSTS = 'FETCH_PARTICULAR_CATEGORY_POSTS'`

Comment: My bad, you're also importing this const in your reducer so you can ignore this, what do you see when clicking `State` at the top-right of redux devtools ?

Comment: I have uploaded the screenshot of my devtools State above in an edit.Please have a look

Comment: I have the whole project with all the files in my github repo. This is the link: https://github.com/PranamiBG/Readable-project/tree/master/src  .If it is some other file causing this error,you can have a look if you want

Comment: I edited all my post it should be ok now, the last issue was the category name in the reducer.

Comment: Wow,this works now.Thank you so so much.I just have 1 doubt in the answer where you said "Now we pass the category property to the action to name the index in which we'll store our array of posts.".Can you please explain little bit what was that for.And thanks once again.Really appreciate your constant effort in trying to resolve this issue.

Comment: This is the property we get in the reducer by `action.category`, we could also access it by `action.payload.data[0].category` but it'll throw an error if there's no posts in the fetched data.

Comment: Okay,now I understood.Thanks a lot for your help.